# loop case statement without exit the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have a simple shell script to select diff task and perform it.
If option 1 is selected it performs that task and it quits the script.

But What I wanted the script to wait for the user to input for another task and perform it until user exit manually.

say first the user selects option 1 and he gets the output. Next, the user wants to select option 2 and should get the output. until he quits the script manually.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "For Fruits [1] "
echo "For Vegetables [2] "
echo "For drinks [3] "
read output
case $output in 
1)
cat 1.txt | tr , '\n' | sort >epackP.txt 
cat 2.txt | tr " " '\n'| /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F "T000" '{print $2}'|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F "+" '{print $1}'|sed '/^$/d' | sort >symmP.txt
diff -ibw 1.txt 2.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "********** Files matched :D **********"  
else
   echo "********** Mismatch found :( **********"
 fi
;;
2)
cat 3.txt | tr , '\n' | sort >epackP.txt 
cat 4.txt | tr " " '\n'| /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F "T00" '{print $2}'|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F "+" '{print $1}'|sed '/^$/d' | sort >symmP.txt
diff -ibw 3.txt 4.txt
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "********** Files matched :D **********"  
else
   echo "********** Mismatch found :( **********"
fi
;;
3)
diff -ibw 5.txt 6.txt 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "********** Files matched :D **********"  
else
   echo "********** Mismatch found :( **********"
 fi
   ;;
*)
echo "retry"
esac
```

Comment: You're looking for a loop. Start right after your first line with `while true; do` and after the last line, add `done`.

Comment: Take a look at the [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) command. It's useful for creating simple menus.

Answer (score 0):

```
while true; do  
 read output
 case $output in 
 1) ...
 2)
 3) break
 esac
done
```

Similar example in details: [Bash-Begginers-Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html)